# Is the combination of water breathing and dance of the fire god breathing, a new breathing or a fast switch between the 2 breathings?

Tags: demon-slayer

In the last episode of the anime of *Kimetsu no Yaiba*, Tanjiro says to himself that he needs to combine both breathings (water breathing and dance of the fire god breathing) to achieve better results (such as lasting longer and being faster), and that's what demon slayers did all the time, they adapted old breathings to their styles, creating new breathings.

In this case, when Tanjiro uses both breathings, we see flames and water flowing around his swings with the sword. What does this mean?

Did he create a new breathing, or is he just quickly switching between the 2 breathings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it a new breathing although it has not been named yet. New breathing were always created by mixing known breathing to suit the slayer's body and skills. It is written in the [wiki itself](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Breathing_Styles):

> **New Breathing Styles are always being created to suit a
> Demon Slayer's combat needs, which results in new weapons being utilized in demon hunting (i.e. flails and whips).** Such Breathing Styles embody a bigger variety of concepts, like animals, plants and emotions (i.e. serpents, flowers and love). When utilizing a Breathing Style, users automatically visualize themselves manipulating the subject behind their style, making it seem as if they were using magic, though those that are less apt and proficient in their style will visualize less than one who is.
>
> **As the different Breathing Styles were created by swordmen  by combining what little they could of Sun Breathing with their own sword skills to display their maximum power, it is possible to mix different Breathing Styles if the user cannot master one particular Breath alone in order to use the stronger aspects of different Styles to compensate.** Tanjiro, realising that he could not master Water Breathing like Giyu Tomioka nor could he handle the strain of Hinokami Kagura, showed to be able to combine the two techniques together in order to have stronger strikes than when he used Water Breathing alone and move for longer periods of time than if he used Hinokami Kagura alone. He did this to save Hinatsuru from Gyutaro.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like he was switching between breathing styles because so far they haven't really introduced any combination breathing but you can use 2 at one time if you have the skill and stamina